# My code for recover.c recovers jpegs correctly but does not pass cs50 check

Tags: c, cs50

Here is the code. I am a beginner at C language so any suggestions to shorten my code will be greatly appreciated. I checked all the 50 images and they look perfect but the code doesn't pass the cs50 check.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* source = fopen("card.raw", "r");



    uint8_t jpg[512];
    int direct = 0;
    int jpgcounter = 0;
    uint8_t checkjpg[4];
    FILE* outputfile ;
    char filename[7] ;

    while(feof(source) == 0)
    {
        fread(jpg,512,1,source);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        {
            checkjpg[i] = jpg[i];
        }

        if( checkjpg[0] == 0xff && checkjpg[1] == 0xd8 && checkjpg[2] == 0xff && checkjpg[3] >= 0xe0 && checkjpg[3] <= 0xef )
        {

            if ( direct == 0 )
            {
              sprintf( filename, "%03d.jpg" , jpgcounter);
              outputfile = fopen(filename, "w");
              fwrite(jpg,512,1,outputfile);
              direct = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(outputfile);
                jpgcounter++;
                sprintf( filename, "%03d.jpg" , jpgcounter);
              outputfile = fopen(filename, "w");
              fwrite(jpg,512,1,outputfile);
            }

        }
        else
        {
           fwrite(jpg,512,1,outputfile) ;
        }
    }
    fclose(outputfile);
    fclose(source);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the major problem is that it does not pass cs50 check so there must be some data that i missed on card.raw or something else and the human eye cannot detect these mistakes in the images but the computer can.

Comment: `char filename[7] ;` is too smal for 3+1+3+1 characters.

Comment: if i use char filename[8] i get a segfault

Comment: If you review the formatted code, you can see a discrepancy in the ghastly if statement that checks for selected content.  That may account for some or all of your problems.  You should think about restructuring your code; variables `checkjpg1` through `checkjpg16` sure look like an array in disguise to me.  Avoid writing stuff out like that; use a data structure (such as an array — a very elementary data structure) to encapsulate the repetition.  When you take a closer look at the data, you should be comparing the first 3 bytes against the known sequence and checking that the 4th is in range.

Comment: There are also a fair number of other questions tagged [tag:cs50] that relate to the JPEG recovery exercise.  You should find help in those.

Comment: I have modified the code as you suggested but the problem still persists.@JonathanLeffler

Comment: The error message seems cut off. Can you please show the full error message? It ends with `error of "/opt/sandbox50/` - that's probably not the  full error, e.g. where is the closing quote sign?

Comment: FYI `3+1+3+1+1=9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. You are never initializing `outputfile`. As a beginner, you should always initialize variables when you declare them. Never write

```
int i;
```

write

```
int i = ...;
```

and give it an initial value (`0`, `-1`, `INT_MAX`, whatever you like). This is very important for pointers. If you write

```
FILE * outputfile;
```

where is that pointer pointing to? Well, it's random. It may point anywhere or nowhere. This is an "invalid" pointer, under no circumstances you must use `outputfile` now as the result of any usage is undefined. But how would you know it's initialized? Well, you can't! You can't as you never assigned it any value you could check for.

Better code would be

```
FILE * outputfile = NULL;
```

as now `outputfile` has a defined value, it is `NULL` and that means you can test if it was initialed

```
if (outputfile == NULL) {
    // Not initialized
} else {
    // Initialized
}
```

Look at your code and think about the following:
What happens if your loop runs for the very first time and the first 512 byte chunk does not match the if-test for `0xffd8ff..`? Then you end in the else-case and this case does the following

```
fwrite(jpg,512,1,outputfile) ;
```

but what value has `outputfile` here? No value, it's totally undefined. You accessing memory at any address and this is very likely to crash your application which is exactly what happens for you. If you had initialized `outputfile` to `NULL`, the correct code would have been:

```
} else if (outputfile != NULL) {
    fwrite(jpg,512,1,outputfile);
}
```

And here comes a super beautified, cleaned up version of the code. The code is untested, I only know it compiles. I know it also got a lot bigger, but please consider there are also tons of comments and the code is checking and handling all expected errors and even prints to `STDERR` what went wrong. If I want I can compact it easily [down to 58 lines](http://rextester.com/DSTMW6543), which is only 7 lines more than your code in the question but your code doesn't catch or print all these errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ( void ) {
    FILE * inputFile = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    if (!inputFile) { // Same as "if (inputFile == NULL)"
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file!\n");
        // Don't close it, it didn't open!
        return 1;
    }

    // Always declare variables in the smallest possible scope!
    // Don't declare anything here you only need in the loop and
    // whose value doesn't need to survive a loop iteration.
    int fileCounter = 0;
    FILE * outputFile = NULL;
    bool writeError =  false;

    for (;;) { // Endless loop, will never terminate on its own
        uint8_t cluster[512];
        // It will read one cluster or nothing at all.
        if (fread(cluster, sizeof(cluster), 1, inputFile) != 1) {
            // If we have an open output file, close it.
            if (outputFile) {
                fclose(outputFile);
                outputFile = NULL; // Not required but good style.
            }
            break; // Terminates the loop!
            // Not reached, code flow continues after the loop.
        }

        // Check if start of new _or first_ JPG file.
        if (cluster[0] == 0xFF && cluster[1] == 0xd8
            && cluster[2] == 0xFF && cluster[3] >= 0xE0 && cluster[3] <= 0xEF
        ) {
            char filename[8];
            snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%03d.jpg", fileCounter++);

            // Start nof an new JPG file.
            // If we have an "old" one, time to close it
            if (outputFile) {
                fclose(outputFile);
            }
            // Open new file
            outputFile = fopen(filename, "w");
            if (!outputFile) {
                // Cannot create output file.
                writeError = true;
                break; // Terminates the loop!
                // Not reached, code flow continues after the loop.
            }
        }

        // If we have an output file, write the cluster to it.
        if (outputFile) {
            if (fwrite(cluster, sizeof(cluster), 1, outputFile) != 1) {
                // Write error.
                writeError = true;
                // Close the file.
                fclose(outputFile);
                break; // Terminates the loop!
                // Not reached, code flow continues after the loop.
            }
        }
    }

    // If we end up here, we ran into one of the "breaks"
    // and now need to find out which one.
    bool exitWithError = false;
    if (writeError) {
        exitWithError = true;
        fprintf(stderr, "Counldn't create/write to output file!\n");
    } else if (ferror(inputFile) != 0) {
        exitWithError = true;
        fprintf(stderr, "Counldn't read from input file file!\n");
    }
    // Otherwise input file was just at the end.

    // Final clanup:
    fclose(inputFile);

    return (exitWithError ? 1 : 0);
}
```

I'm sharing this code with you as learning certain coding concepts is probably easiest by just looking how other people write code.

Comment: Great advice. I learnt my lesson as to why initialisation is important .Thanks a lot @Mecki

Comment: @mithilesh I also added a cleaned up version of your code with proper error handling - like "how would I have coded that". Maybe this gives you some ideas how to improve your code in the future. I cannot test it but I know it compiles.

Comment: not only does it teach me stylistic correctness but also some new concepts. Thanks a lot .Wish i had enough rep to upvote :p